# Why does my useEffect run if I'm not expecting it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a search engine using an input and a button that I hope will execute the search but when I just enter a letter in the input that sets the search value of useState my useEffect is executed even though search is not found in the useEffect dependency array.

Input:

```
<div className="flex gap-1">
    <input className="border-1 border-2 border-solid rounded border-slate-300" value={search} onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)} />
    <button onClick={() => handleSearch()} <FiSearch/></button>
</div>
```

handleSearch()

```
const handleSearch = async () => { 
   setLimitPage(10)
   setPage(1)
   await getProducts(limitPage, page, search)
}
```

my useEffect that is executed without being expected that way as soon as search changes

```
useEffect (() => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    getProducts(limitPage, page, search) 
    setTotalDocs(products.products?.totalDocs)
    setTotalPages(products.products?.totalPages)
    setCurrentPage(products.products?.page)
    setNextPage(products.products?.hasNextPage)
    setPreviousPage(products.products?.hasPrevPage)

    const totalPages = Math.ceil(totalDocs/limitPage)
    const links = []
    for (let i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
        links[i] = i
    }
    setNumbers(links)
}, [products, limitPage, page ])
```

I don't understand how I can avoid this so that I can use my search function before useEffect is executed

Comment: limitPage and page  are dependencies of your useEffect hook, so of course when it changes it's going to run the useEffect

Comment: Try removing limitPage and page from your dependency array in your useEffect hook. That way, it'll only run when the products array changes (assuming you have that set up correctly)

Comment: Ok, if I remove what you mention it works the same but the problem persists, if I enter a single letter in the search input it executes my useEffect immediately

Comment: We would need to see more of your code. If you only have `products` in your dependency array, it will only run when that value is updated. My guess is you're using a controlled input as a dependency, and those update every character (unlike an uncontrolled input). Post the entire code.